# Tuning "copy to tmp table" for batch size

Tags: mysql, innodb

When altering a table using InnoDB, the "copy to tmp table" step seems to execute in batches of 10,000 - you can see this if you watch the row transactions in innotop...

Is there a setting that alters the batch size "copy to tmp table" uses?

We're using innodb_log_file_size=8G so I was wondering if I would get better performance with larger transactions..

Answer (score 0):

use percona's [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html)

chunk option(chunk-size, chunk-time, etc... ) is that you want setting

Comment: I can't use pt-online-schema-change because this table uses virtual columns from MariaDB which is not supported (bug reported already to percona)..  The question is if theres a way to tune this on the innodb side of things.